# Create a time counter to insert in array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem with creating a time in milliseconds to add to an array.

I have an app that reads from two external devices. So I need to insert a time about when these data are read.

I have a function like this:

```
async setupNotifications1(device) {
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();
    device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
      service,
      this.AccGyrMg,
      (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [...acc_dx] = [2, 4, 6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({

          acc_dx,
          array_acc_dx: [  
            ...state.array_acc_dx, 
            [acc_dx],
          ]
        }));

    /* pressure */ 
    device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
      service,
      this.Pressure,
      (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64"); 
        const [...pressure_dx] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].map(index => buf.readUInt16LE(index)); 
        this.setState(state => ({
          pressure_dx,
          array_pressure_dx: [
            ...state.array_pressure_dx, 
            [pressure_dx]
          ]
        }));
      }
    );
```

How can I create a time to concatenate at [...acc_dx] and [pressure_dx] ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using setTimeout() for doing this.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers

So in your case you could have something like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    addToArray();
    }, 300);
```

Comment: And how can I insert in array? I should obtain something like [time, [acceleration]]